# IntelliJ 14 - removing extra JARs from classpath

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ 14.1.7 and I have some weird behaviour that is popping up in one of my projects but not another. I can't for the life of me see the difference in configurations or how to fix it.

In both Project A and Project B I've added `ojdbc8.jar` as a dependency via "Project Structure"->"Modules".

In Project A I go to "Edit Configurations" and select one of my run configs, and next to the "Add --classpath" checkbox the listing includes only the OJDBC path I added. When I check the box and run this the application runs fine.

In Project B I go to "Edit Configurations" and select one of my run configs, and next to the "Add --classpath" checkbox the listing includes a whole bunch of jars in my `$HOME/.m2/repository` directory, followed by the OJDBC path I added. When I check the box and run this the application dies immediately with the error:

```
|Loading Grails 2.5.6
Error |
Error executing script RunApp: tried to access method com.google.common.collect.MapMaker.makeComputingMap(Lcom/google/common/base/Function;)Ljava/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap; from class com.google.inject.internal.Annotations$AnnotationChecker (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

As far as I can tell the run configurations are otherwise the same. I haven't been able to find anything setting the extra classpath JARs for Project B, but it's obviously being set somewhere. There's nothing unusual in the `.classpath` file, and I can't find any relevant differences in the settings for the two projects. I've tried clearing out the `.m2` directory and restarting IntelliJ but the situation doesn't change. Can someone suggest where I ought to look for these classpath entries being set?

Comment: Are you using Maven or some other build system? I find it odd that you'd be expecting to manage dependencies directly in IDEA, but also be looking in places like .classpath and .m2 for dependencies.

Comment: @PeterCooperJr. Yes, I'm using Maven. I mentioned `.classpath` and `m2` to rule out any interference from those locations -- I'm not suggesting that they're the problem.

Comment: Then why are you trying to manage dependencies using "Project Structure" instead of using Maven?

Comment: I'm only trying to manage these dependencies for local execution purposes. When deployed, the OJDBC JAR is present system-wide rather than in my application WAR. But when I `run-app` locally I need some way to point the application at this JAR on my development machine.

Comment: @DavidLeaman IntelliJ IDEA doesn't support it yet: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-160167.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thanks for pointing that out -- it certainly seems related. But somehow, something _is_ setting my run config classpath. And it's happening for some projects and not others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried everything I could think of to avoid having to do this, but I finally deleted the `.idea` directory and `*.iml` files and reimported the project. Not really a satisfying solution, but at least my project is running properly now.

Answer (score 0):

You could reimport all maven projects from the Maven tab as shown bellow:
[image]